# change the background of the application developed using flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile-application, flutter-theme, flutter-background

I want to develop an application using Flutter language. I want to make the background color of my application linear and I want to add it to the theme. There are two white circles at the top of the background and I want them to be responsive. And finally, there is an image on the opening screen, I want it to be responsive in the same way. What I want from you is to find an answer to the question "Can I make the background color linear in the theme of the application?"

I am sharing sample pictures.

[background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O2MY.png)

[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcjrz.png)

[opening screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzpcx.png)